# Jquery live() alternative in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have code:

```
 events: {
            'click .bet-block': 'clickOdd',
        },
```

my problem is that when you **add a dynamic element** this event dont work...
As the reach of method Jquery live in Backbone?

Comment: could you please create jsfiddle? Looks like you have some wrong way appending elements

Comment: The simplest method rerender view! Another way is add events in append method

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to work add this line in your view after you add the dynamic element :

```
this.delegateEvents();
```

Comment: What do I do if I dynamically add by native javascript(appendChild) not Backbone.View?

Comment: You have to keep a reference to your Backbone.View (let's say myView) and call its delegateEvents `myView.delegateEvents();` it's the only way to bind your view events.